# Unable to generate TypeORM migrations when electron ABI differs from installed node

Tags: typescript, electron, typeorm, better-sqlite3

Currently building better-sqlite3 from sources and that works fine but running typeorm migration:generate ends up failing as it uses my local node which has a different ABI version. I would prefer not to have to rebuild before/after migrations if at all possible. From what I can tell no node release is using the electron ABI and that also looks difficult to line up always from looking at electron & node releases.

I tried doing the following to no avail though it helped out for running jest tests.

```
yarn ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE=true ./node_modules/.bin/electron -r ts-node/register ./node_modules/.bin/typeorm -f path/to/ormconfig.ts migration:generate -n MigrationName
```

EDIT: Got around this by modifying: `node_modules/typeorm/cli.js`

For the args processing replace the final `".argv;"` with `".parse(process.argv.slice(2));"`

Answer (score 0):

Got around this by modifying `node_modules/typeorm/cli.js` For the args processing replace the final

```
.argv;
```

with

```
.parse(process.argv.slice(2));
```